# Is there a CASE Tool for modelling spatial databases?

Tags: postgis, modelling

Does anyone knows if there is a CASE Tool that would be possible for modelling spatial tables? I need to create a model and export it to SQL or a database directly. I'm using PostGIS.

Answer (score 12):

See [Moskitt Geo](http://www.prodevelop.es/en/products/MOSKitt/MOSKittGeo) for this. Some demos available on youtube http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ed-Sb66llXY and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=motlsfzFXn0

For the moment, there are some problems with type for generated sql.

After not especially for gis database but PostgreSQL in general, see

- [SQL Power Architect](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/)
- [DBDesigner fork](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdesigner-fork/)
- [PgModeler](http://www.pgmodeler.com.br)

The first use JDBC, so it keeps PK (Primary Key) and FK (Foreign Key) when reverse engineering, the second use ODBC, so it only retrieves tables structures but no PK or FK. The last one is one of the recent tools and lack reverse engineering (ability to generate visual schema from tables structures)

The 3 previous tools can create database from the schema you create or generate from a pre-existing database, the schema (the second process is usually call reverse engineering)

An other tool can be [Perceptory](http://sirs.scg.ulaval.ca/perceptory) but it uses Visio and Oracle and seems to not be maintained.
You can have a look on [MADS Tools](http://cs.ulb.ac.be/mads_tools/) for modeling time geospatial database

If your looking for others database case tools, a good list can be found on the LASIG EPFL website http://lasig2.epfl.ch/services/case/case.html (sorry, in french)

Comment: what do the acronyms PK and FK mean?

Comment: PK = Primary Key and FK = Foreign Key. Clearer? I've edited my answer due to your feedback

Answer (score 5):

If money is not an issue then [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/press/articles/geospatial-interoperability.html) is the tool you are looking for. If you need it to be free, you can check out [Humboldt's Geomodel Editor](http://www.dhpanel.eu/humboldt-framework/geomodel-editor.html).

[image]

Both have support for spatial data types.

Answer (score -2):

you can check out [GeoKettle](http://www.spatialytics.org/projects/geokettle/) for your request - ETL tool. you can find a good documentation [here](http://www.slideshare.net/Spatialytics/geokettle-20-workshop-foss4g-2011). it is an open source project and has lots of features.

Extract data from:

```
Spatial database types: PostGIS, Oracle spatial, MySQL,  Microsoft SQL Server 2008*, Ingres* and IBM DB2*
SOLAP (Spatial OLAP) system: GeoMondrian
Geo files (data formats): Shapefile, GML, KML, OGR
OGC Web services: Sensor Observation Service (SOS), Catalogue Web Service (CSW)
```

[image: geokettle]

What is GeoKettle :

> GeoKettle is a powerful, metadata-driven Spatial ETL tool dedicated to
>   the integration of different spatial data sources for building and
>   updating geospatial data warehouses. GeoKettle enables the Extraction
>   of data from data sources, the Transformation of data in order to
>   correct errors, make some data cleansing, change the data structure,
>   make them compliant to defined standards, and the Loading of
>   transformed data into a target DataBase Management System (DBMS) in
>   OLTP or OLAP/SOLAP mode, GIS file or Geospatial Web Service.
>
> GeoKettle is a spatially-enabled version of the generic ETL tool
>   Kettle (Pentaho Data Integration). GeoKettle also benefits from
>   Geospatial capabilities from mature, robust and well know Open Source
>   libraries like JTS, GeoTools, deegree, OGR and, via a plugin,
>   Sextante.

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Kettle's for integration, not modeling. What the OP needs is something for database design and data modeling.