# Database Diagrammer for PostGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis

Is there a application, or QGIS plugin to generate database diagrams (specifically for PostGIS) similar to the ESRI Diagrammer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer is directly related to [this existing question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4528/is-there-a-case-tool-for-modelling-spatial-databases/) about case tools. The function you expect is call reverse engineering in this tools

Personnaly, I use [SQL Power Architect](http://code.google.com/p/power-architect/)